# Why doesn't `aplay -L` list my Bluetooth device

Tags: debian, command-line, bluetooth

I connected to my Bluetooth speakers with the UI and it is confirmed that I'm properly paired and connected with sound and visual indicators.

However, I typed `aplay -L` with command line and the Bluetooth device isn't listed. The list is exactly the same when Bluetooth is shut down.

Is there any reason for Bluetooth device being perfectly recognized by the computer's UI, but not by command line `aplay`? How can I make it appear in the list of devices?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that what you call your UI is something that has launched *Pulsaudio* which achieves all the magic.

*Aplay* is ALSA bare-metal recorder/player. It can work with (and aplay -l will actually list) all sound cards driven by whatever ALSA driver installed.

As far as I know there is no ALSA driver for bluetooth sound devices.

Therefore, you will need [bluez-alsa](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa) which enables you to create a virtual device (PCM) to enable alsa compatible players/recorders to directly (with no need for pulseaudio) use your bluetooth sound device.

Comment: I think I properly installed bluez-alsa, following what is said in the link (I don't know ho to check if it actually went well). But I still don't have the bluetooth device on my list.

Comment: Did you configure your .asoundrc adequately (defaults.bluealsa.service "org.bluealsa"
defaults.bluealsa.device "XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"
defaults.bluealsa.profile "a2dp"
defaults.bluealsa.delay 1000à)... launched bluetoothctl prior to aplay -D bluealsa... ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but I'll make some research and let you know if I found anything. Thanks.

Comment: What I mean is detailed at the bottom of the page I linked to in my answer.